# (Python) Plotting pressure as function of X,Y,Z

Tags: python, plot, vtk

Basically, I am trying to plot pressure as function of X,Y,Z. Can any one give me an example on how to do it?

Some additional information:

X,Y,Z represent position in the domain;

Pressure represent the intensity

I am retrieving the dataset from a FILE HDF5.

```
len(X) = 10
len(Y) = 1
len(Z) = 636
```

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

Here is my initial piece of code that retrieves the data

```
import h5py

FILE_INPUT = "../output/hdf5/Diagramme_rayonnement_3D.h5"
DATASET_NAME = "/dset"
ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "Calculation Attributes"

file = h5py.File(FILE_INPUT)
dset = file[DATASET_NAME]
attr = dset.attrs[ATTRIBUTE_NAME]
attr = {'Nx': attr[0], 'Ny': attr[1], 'Nz': attr[2], 'Nfreq': attr[3], 'deltaX': attr[4], 
        'deltaY': attr[5], 'deltaZ': attr[6], 'deltaF': attr[7], 'Fmin': attr[8]}

X = [x * attr['deltaX'] for x in range(int(attr['Nx']))]
Y = [y * attr['deltaY'] for y in range(int(attr['Ny']))]
Z = [z * attr['deltaZ'] for z in range(int(attr['Nz']))]
Frequencies = [freq * attr['deltaF'] for freq in range(int(attr['Nfreq']))]
Frequencies += attr['Fmin']
```

As you can see, I have this dataset that I need to plot which is a 4D array. The first index refers to the Frequency. The second, third and forth index refer to position in the domain. And the value stored represent the pressure(Intensity).
What I need to do is to create a GUI that exhibits the plot by frequency. So we are left with a 3D array with a pressure value. Those data are being generated by a C/C++ code. So depending on the config file, the values may change.

I left len(Y) = 1 on purpose to speed up the results.

I have no idea on where to start. Can you please guide me.

PS: I would really prefere to use VTK solution. But it is not necessarily a constraint.

Comment: Could you clarify if the pressure is in the variable `Z` or if it's another variable? If it's the latter case, then you should have a variable that is of shape `(10, 1, 636)` (or comparable). If it's the latter case (which I guess) then you have pressure as a function of 3 dimensional space. It is typically represented by plotting the coordinates in space using a colormap related to the pressure.

Comment: Hello, Yes you guess it right! I couldn't explain it better. I have pressure as function of 3D space. Any ideias?

Comment: Several ideas, in fact. But writing them all out would take me too much time, whereas you should really try to show what you have tried already (that's how Stackoverflow works). Your tags seem to suggest you want a solution in vtk, is this really true? Also, your current dataset where there's only 1 y-coordinate, seems to suggest you have a slice of 3D space (i.e. a plane) for which the pressure profile can be visualised far more easily. Can you update your question to provide more info on (1) if you really want a vtk solution, (2) if your current problem is only about 2D slices.

Comment: I see Oliver. The truth is that I have done little plot in my life. I really don't know how to even begin. I just have this simple code that retrieves the dataset in an HDF5 file which which is a 3D array. I know that we I have to plot the elements in function of X,Y,Z. Yes, ideally it would be better if I use vtk solution. 
I will update my question. Thanks for the guideline.

Answer (score 0):

For the plotting part:
https://plot.ly/python/3d-wireframe-plots/

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import numpy as np

# Creating the data
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
xGrid, yGrid = np.meshgrid(y, x)
R = np.sqrt(xGrid ** 2 + yGrid ** 2)
z = np.sin(R)

# Creating the plot
lines = []
line_marker = dict(color='#0066FF', width=2)
for i, j, k in zip(xGrid, yGrid, z):
    lines.append(go.Scatter3d(x=i, y=j, z=k, mode='lines', line=line_marker))

layout = go.Layout(
    title='Wireframe Plot',
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(
            gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            showbackground=True,
            backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            showbackground=True,
            backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
        ),
        zaxis=dict(
            gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            showbackground=True,
            backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
        )
    ),
    showlegend=False,
)
fig = go.Figure(data=lines, layout=layout)
plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='wireframe_plot')
```